# exsheet print several exams same document

Tags: loops, exsheets, questionnaire

How to print several exams in the same document using `exsheets`?

I need to print several exams using

```
\includequestions[random=1]{easy}
\includequestions[random=1]{medium}
\includequestions[random=1]{hard}
```

Comment: You don't say much about what exactly you want to do, but I think this  should be relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139531/how-can-i-automate-the-workflow-for-producing-multiple-versions-of-a-document and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document

Comment: It would also be useful to add details about what goes wrong when you try to do what you want to do - what errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite unclear to me. A basic example of what I *think* you want would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

% declare a class `difficulties':
\DeclareQuestionClass{difficulty}{difficulties}

% the external file that holds the exercises
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{my-exercises.tex}
\begin{question}[difficulty=easy]
  First easy question.  
\end{question}
\begin{question}[difficulty=easy]
  Second easy question.  
\end{question}
\begin{question}[difficulty=easy]
  Third easy question.  
\end{question}
\begin{question}[difficulty=medium]
  First medium question.  
\end{question}
\begin{question}[difficulty=medium]
  Second medium question.  
\end{question}
\begin{question}[difficulty=medium]
  Third medium question.  
\end{question}
\begin{question}[difficulty=hard]
  First hard question.  
\end{question}
\begin{question}[difficulty=hard]
  Second hard question.  
\end{question}
\begin{question}[difficulty=hard]
  Third hard question.  
\end{question}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\SetupExSheets{use-difficulties={easy}}
\includequestions[random=1]{my-exercises}

\SetupExSheets{use-difficulties={medium}}
\includequestions[random=1]{my-exercises}

\SetupExSheets{use-difficulties={hard}}
\includequestions[random=1]{my-exercises}

\end{document}
```

[image]