# Can I pass LaTeX commands to latexmk instead of a filename?

Tags: input, latexmk, makefile

This is a follow-up to [How can I automate the workflow for producing multiple versions of a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139531/how-can-i-automate-the-workflow-for-producing-multiple-versions-of-a-document?lq=1)

Here is toy example of my problem. I want to automate the generation of two slightly different versions of a document. Each one should be generated using `latexmk`. In one version, no class option should be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

In the other, some class option should be used, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

Of course, I could

1. compile once without the class option,
2. edit my `.tex` file and manually add the class option,
3. compile a second time,

but this approach lacks automation. Alternatively, I could use two files:

```
% withoutoption.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

and

```
% withoption.tex
\PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{article}
\input{withoutoption.tex}
```

but, ideally, I'd like to only have one file to maintain, and pass class options from outside the `.tex` file (in a makefile). From [Martin Scharrer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22525/21891), I know I can pass a class option *without* having to edit the file, like so:

```
pdflatex "\PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{article}\input{foo}"
```

I'd like to use `latexmk` instead of `pdflatex`, though, and I can't figure out how the approach above would translate to `latexmk`. I must admit I'm not very familiar with the `latexmk` syntax, but I've scanned the documentation, and it appears `latexmk` can only accept a filename, not an argument of the form

```
"\PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{article}\input{foo}"
```

Did I miss something? Can `latexmk` be used in this fashion?

Comment: What about the `-latex="..."` argument? You could pass that with an hard-coded call to `latex` with the appropriate arguments...I think `latexmk` "needs" files is that it tries to detect changes, if you onlyrun it once this should be fine...

Comment: @Bordaigorl Could you please elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the `-latex` or `-pdflatex` options.
I'll use `pdflatex` for the examples but it should work with `latex` as well.

```
latexmk -pdf article
```

will look for `article.tex`, invoke the command associated with the pdflatex option which by default is

```
"pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S %O"
```

where `%S` is replaced by the filename and `%O` by the options.

So to produce the `twocolumn` version you could run

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex='pdflatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 "\PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{article}\input{%S}"' article
```

and you would find the twocolumns version in `article.pdf`.
The nice thing is that you can create an alias for `latexmk -pdf -pdflatex='pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 "\PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{article}\input{%S}" %O'` and run it on different tex files to obtain the twocolumn version of each.

I moved `%O` before the other options because this seems to enable using `-jobname=name` as an option of `latexmk` (see comments).

Now this is not enough because if you then re run `latexmk -pdf article` without making changes to `article.tex`, `latexmk` would fail to recognise the options have changed and will not recompile the document.
So to force that you can add the `-g` option.

Comment: Let me try that `:)`

Comment: Great. Exactly what I wanted. There is only one weird thing.  If I want to use a different jobname (`foo`, say), I have to use `-jobname=foo` in two different places:`latexmk -jobname=foo -pdf -pdflatex='pdflatex -jobname=foo -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 "\PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{article}\input{%S}" %O' article`. Otherwise, I get an error saying `(Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'foo.log'`.

Comment: @Jubobs strange, passing `-jobname=foo` to latexmk only seems to work for me (version 4.35 on Ubuntu)...I think passing that would forward it to the command via `%O`.

Comment: although using it into the `-pdflatex` argument would allow you to use it as `-jobname=twocols-%S`

Comment: Using `%O` earlier seems to do the trick: I got it to work with `latexmk -jobname=foo -pdf -pdflatex='pdflatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 "\PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{article}\input{%S}"' article`

Comment: Yes, should have told you I tried with `%O` as first arg!

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the help! Getting more familiar with `latexmk` is now on my "laundry list".

Comment: Thanks again. You can expect a [bounty](http://www.candywarehouse.com/assets/item/large/Mars-Bounty-Bar.jpg) `:)`

Comment: glad I could help! =D