# How to compile the same input file for each of LaTeX font packages installed in our machine?

Tags: fonts, programming, shell-escape

[image]

Inspired by my question [How to create a PDF presentation for each available Beamer theme automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67861/19356), now I want to compile my input file for each available LaTeX font package installed in my machine.

Listing each font name in `\foreach` as follows does not seem a good idea as it will not accommodate all available packages as well as it is not up-to-date.

```
% the file name of this code is inputfile.tex
% compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape inputfile.tex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{\loadfont}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,...,26}{\char\numexpr\x+64\relax\char\numexpr\x+96\relax\space}
\begin{align*}
\sin (\alpha \pm\beta) &=\sin\alpha \cos \beta \pm \cos\alpha \sin\beta\\
\mathscr{L}\left\{f(t)\right\} &= F(s)\\
\vec{F} &= m\frac{\textrm{d}\vec{v}(t)}{\textrm{d}t}\\
\int_a^b f(x)\, \textrm{d}x &= F(b) -F(a)\\
\vec \nabla \cdot \vec \nabla \times A &= \vec\nabla  \times  \nabla U
\end{align*}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\dojob#1{\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=template-#1 "\def\noexpand\loadfont{#1} \noexpand\input{template}"}}


\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {bera,palatino,mathpazo,helvet,libertine}
{%
    \dojob{\x}%
    \preview
    \section{\x}
    \includegraphics{template-\x}
    \endpreview
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A list of all installed packages (the list includes not only font packages but also other packages) can be done easily with this method [How to print the list of packages installed on TeX Live to a file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73859/19356). However, I have no idea to filter the list and remove the non-font packages.

How to compile the same input file for each of LaTeX font packages installed in our machine?

Comment: I want to distribute my lecture notes to my students where each of them gets a copy with a unique font. Does it seem to be fun?

Comment: That's imho not possible without a lot of manual work.  "font packages" don't have an identifiable structure like beamer themes. You could try to get a sensible list from the fd-files, but there no guarantee that the corresponding fonts exist and will still miss some fonts.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot, I respect your opinion but IMHO it does not seem to be funny. What is the reason to change the font for each student?

Comment: @Sigur: Who said it becomes funny? It will be fun not funny.

Comment: +1 Although no exact idea, but this kind of automation can be done easily by Unix Power tools(shell,sed,awk,grep) or perl since TeX engines can be called any number of times,files can be parsed and rewritten with new set of fonts to get multiple .pdf's similar to Herbert example in Linked Q. Scripting has infinite power in Unix and even on windows with `cygwin` etc..

Comment: This will not do exactly what you want but it could do some of it if you adapted it, I think. http://ctan.org/pkg/fontsampler is designed to produce a sample of the standard fonts installed for TeX. But you could easily adapt the source to typeset your own sample. If you have additional fonts installed, though, you'd need to add those yourself, I think. The previous comment mentioned using Unix tools. I'm not sure how easy this would be to automate, though. There's a lot of variation in the kind and degree of support for different fonts.

Comment: Seriously, this seems to be more trouble than it's worth. Is there a particular point (Yes, yes, i't "fun", of course it is), perhaps you can somehow achieve your goal differently. Alternatively, for just about as much fun as most people can handle on an empty stomach, just use Comic Sans MS for your notes.

Comment: If you really plan to distribute your lecture notes as you say, I think that aiding and abetting you is unethical aside from any other considerations. Hopefully this was a joke.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution, assuming you have access to a UNIX¹ system with a TeX installation.

Inside the working directory of your project

1. Create a `main` subdirectory holding the files of your document.
2. Edit the preamble of your document, so that it includes a statement `input{fontsetup}`.
3. For each font package you want to test, create a subdirectory holding a single file `fontsetup.tex` responsible for setting up the font you want.
4. In your directory project, create a `build.sh` shell script that you will run to produce your outputs, as described below.

The `build.sh` script may look like, where I assume your main document file is `galley.tex` and that your packages are 'lmodern mathpple'

```
#!/bin/sh
pkg_list='mathpple lmodern'
for pkg in "$pkg_list"; do
  env TEXINPUTS="main:$pkg:." tex -jobname $pkg galley.tex
done
```

Depending on your system, you may replace the `pkg_list` assignment by

```
pkg_list=`find . -type d \( -name main -prune -o -print \)`
```

which saves you the trouble from maintaining the list.

Now you still have to prepare directories for each package you want to test—and update the `pkg_list` variable. To help you create the following `fontsetup.sh` script in your project directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
for pkg in "$@"; do
   install -d $pkg
   printf '\\usepackge{%s}\n' $pkg > $pkg/fontsetup.tex
done
```

Give the execute bit to the scripts and give it a try with

```
$ ./fontsetup.sh mathpple lmodern
$ ./build.sh
```

The first command creates a directory for each package and a canonical `fontsetup.tex` file.  The second command processes each package.

Having a different file for each font package is nice, because it allows you to add font-specific customisations.

¹ I mean *FreeBSD* of course!

Comment: Plus one: How about Windows version as Unix is not my interest right now? :-)

Comment: It is nice to learn Unix, because after this you can start to let the computer work for you—and this is what computer are for, aren't they? If you know any programming language you can use on windows, you can adapt the scripts above.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot By the way I find your idea giving exam sheets to your students, each with a different font, actually very funny! :-)

Comment: Yes. I love doing "crazy" (chaos oriented) ideas. :-)

Comment: @kissmyarmpit: On windows, it's easy! In the text editor, select with the mouse the text you want to be repeated. Ctrl-C, ctrl-v, enter, ctrl-v. Change to the application that lists the font names. Double-click on the font name. Then alt-tab back to the text editor. Put the mouse pointer over the place you are supposed to write the font name. Left-click (if do not have a left-handed mouse setting). Ctrl-v. Repeat for each font you want. After all that, click on the appropriate button to generate the PDF. Click on "open pdf". :-P

Answer (score 6):

I have not enough reputation for a comment, even though this is meant as one and not an answer.

Probably, this question and the answers might be helpful for you: [What fonts are installed on my box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/what-fonts-are-installed-on-my-box)

Note, that one answer states, that [all fonts on this page](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) should be available on a complete LaTeX-Install. But if you want to use some system fonts, this list might not be complete.

Answer (score 6):

Really this should be done with a simple shell script or other Unix tool that generates a simple wrapper document, which loads your text. But here's a more TeX-centric solution. It has the benefit that you can use just one LaTeX document, which is not generated or modified programmatically.

A little-used feature of (La)TeX is that its argument can be a sequence of TeX commands instead of a filename. So, write your document so that the font is given by a macro, undefined in the document itself. Then every invocation can define the macro to be a different font.

The document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{\myfont}

\begin{document}
Hello, Marienplatz!
\end{document}
```

From the Unix, Windows or VM/CMS command line:

```sh
% pdflatex "\def\myfont{palatino}\input{handout.tex}"
% mv handout.pdf palatino.pdf
% pdflatex "\def\myfont{times}\input{handout.tex}"
% mv handout.pdf times.pdf
  etc.
```

**Addendum:**
Indeed the above requires you to know and insert the font names manually, so it's not really what you're after. You only asked for *Latex* font packages, but would you settle for using all system fonts? Here's a little bash script for OS X, that'll generate versions for all installed truetype fonts:

```sh
for F in /Library/Fonts/*.ttf
do
   FONT=`basename "$F" .ttf`
   xelatex "\def\myfont{$FONT}\input{handout.tex}"
   mv handout.pdf "$FONT".pdf
done
```

Repeat for `.otf` and `.ttc`, if you have that many students. (Since this uses XeLaTeX, replace `\usepackage{\myfont}` with `\setmainfont{\myfont}` in `handout.tex`)

**Edit 2:** 
And here is a Windows version, using the command `fc-list` from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12881) to list usable fonts:

```sh
FOR /F %F IN ('fc-list :outline -f "%{family}\n"') DO 
   xelatex "\def\myfont{%F}\input{handout.tex}"; move handout.pdf %F.pdf
```

You are welcome.

Comment: Apologies, if you _are_ interested in non-latex solutions! (Or do I still misunderstand which part I misparsed?)

Comment: I hope I've made partial amends now.

Comment: I think I need a solution that works on Windows. :-) But +1 for your effort.

Comment: Do you have the command [`fc-list`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12881/12092) in your TeX distribution?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot Windows might have PowerShell Scripting (similar to Unix shell script I suppose), I have no idea whether anyone can adapt the current answers to a PowerShell script. Otherwise `Cygwin` is the best bet.

Comment: @Donut, with a list of fonts from `fc-list`, the `xelatex` solution shouldn't be hard to port to Windows (even without powershell). I'll check if I get a chance.

Comment: "Since this uses XeLaTeX, replace `\usepackage{\myfont}` with `\setmainfont{\myfont}` in `handout.tex`)".  Wasn't that clear enough?

Comment: I cannot make it work.