# PDF fonts are very thin

Tags: fonts, pdf

I found that the fonts in my pdf file are very thin while printing. I use the path `latex->dvi->ps->pdf`.

I tried including

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

But I got the same result. I am using texlive-2013 on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

Comment: Well, “thin” is a rather vague concept. Unless it's a problem, you get the fonts you use. If you use the default Computer Modern (or Latin Modern), it's true that it's thinner than many other fonts. If you don't need that font, but want a thicker one: use it! For instance loading one of this packages: `fourier`, `newtxtext`, `XCharter`, `libertine`, `gentium`, `Alegreya`, `kpfonts`, …

Comment: The problem might be in the lack of the CM-Super fonts. Try `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Comment: @ egreg: I tried it. No visible change.

Answer (score 8):

Just to ease you to choose the better font conveniently. Apparently, I have made it several decades ago, [here (click)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146892/19356).

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,multi]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{\fonttouse}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This is an equation just for fun.
\[
\int_a^b f(x)\, \mathrm{d} x = F(b) -F(a)
\]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{pgffor,graphicx}

\def\dojob#1{\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=template-#1 "\def\noexpand\fonttouse{#1} \noexpand\input{template.tex}"}}
\def\fontlist{kpfonts, fourier, newtxtext, XCharter, libertine, gentium, Alegreya}


\begin{document}
\foreach \x in \fontlist {%
\dojob{\x}
\preview
\section*{\x}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{template-\x}
\end{center}
\endpreview
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Thanks for your nice effort. But I found some issue with the math fonts. Hence I am following the instructions given at http://www.khirevich.com/latex/font/

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```